# Can not insert records into database in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am beginner in CodeIgniter. I want to insert records in database. Here is my view file. I save view file as a `register.php` and my model file as `register_insert.php` and controller file as `register.php` and my table name in mysql is "register".

View

```
<?php $this->load->view('layot/header'); ?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Register</title>
  <style>
    td {
   border:none;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<form method="POST" action="register">
<table border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>User Name : <input type="text" name="u_nm"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Password : <input type="text" name="pwd"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-Mail: <input type="text" name="eid"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Contact No : <input type="text" name="cno"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mobile No : <input type="text" name="mbo"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>
</table>
```

This is my controller file..

```
    public function index()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $data = array(
            'u_nm' => $this->input->post('u_nm'),
            'pwd' => $this->input->post('pwd'),
            'eid' => $this->input->post('eid'),
            'cno' => $this->input->post('cno'),
            'mbo' => $this->input->post('mbo'),
             );
            $this->register_insert->form_insert($data);
        }
        $this->load->view('register');
    }

  }
?>
```

This is my model file..

```
<?php
class Register extends CI_Model
{

   function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
   }
   function form_insert($data){
       $this->db->insert('register', $data);
   }
}
?>
}

?>
```

Comment: whats the question anyway?

Comment: insert is not working i can not insert records in my table @Ghost

Comment: In Your Model, model name is Register, but in your Controller, you using 'register_insert'. This might not work this way. You need to load the model with `$this->load->model("register");` before use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to load model register in controller

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('register');
}
```

In function index, you need to call class name register

```
public function index()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $data = array(
            'u_nm' => $this->input->post('u_nm'),
            'pwd' => $this->input->post('pwd'),
            'eid' => $this->input->post('eid'),
            'cno' => $this->input->post('cno'),
            'mbo' => $this->input->post('mbo'),
             );
            $this->register->form_insert($data);
        }
        $this->load->view('register');
    }

  }
```

And in model you can return the last insert id after inserted

```
public function form_inssert($data){
   $this->db->insert('register',$data);
   return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: if i am load model in my old code before dataarray than it is proper or not.. @phongphu10

Comment: when you load model in function construct of the controller, you can call to model in everywhere in that controller. If you don't load model in function construct, you may load it in each action of controller when you need to use it

Comment: i am load my model in controller file than it's shows me blank page. me load model before submit button in controller file.. if me comment that line than it's show me from and if me load model before submit button than it is shows me a blank page..

Answer (score 0):

This is my controller file

```
<?php 
  class Register extends CI_Controller{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('register_insert');
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $data = array(
            'u_nm' => $this->input->post('u_nm'),
            'pwd' => $this->input->post('pwd'),
            'eid' => $this->input->post('eid'),
            'cno' => $this->input->post('cno'),
            'mbo' => $this->input->post('mbo'),
             );
            $this->register_insert->form_insert($data);
        }
        $this->load->view('register');
    }

  }
?>
```

And This is my model file

```
<?php
class Register_insert extends CI_Model
{
  function __construct() 
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }
  function form_insert($data)
  {
    $this->db->insert('register', $data);
  }
}
?>
```

My mistake is naming of my model class name is "Register_insert" and my old class name is Register that is why my model is not load properly..

Answer (score 0):

in your controller function as given below:

```
public function index()
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $data = array(
        'u_nm' => $this->input->post('u_nm'),
        'pwd' => $this->input->post('pwd'),
        'eid' => $this->input->post('eid'),
        'cno' => $this->input->post('cno'),
        'mbo' => $this->input->post('mbo'),
         );
        $this->register_insert->form_insert($data);
        redirect('register');
    }
    $this->load->view('register');
}

}
```

in your model file as given below :

```
function form_insert($data){
   $this->db->insert('register', $data);
   return true;
}
```

try this now u get result

Answer (score 0):

You may try this for your view code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Register</title>
  <style>
    td {
   border:none;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<table border="1" align="center">
  <?php echo form_open('register/register_insert'); ?>
  <tr>
    <td>User name:<?php echo form_input('u_nm'); ?></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password :<?php echo form_input('pwd'); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-Mail: <?php echo form_input('eid'); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Contact No : <?php echo form_input('cno'); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mobile No : <?php echo form_input('mbo'); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"></td>
  </tr>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</table>
</form>
</html>
</table>
```

It is more easier using the form helper. You can autoload this in the autoload.php config file like this:

```html
$autoload['helper'] = array('form');
```

This will be your controller:

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class register extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('register');
    }

  public function register_insert()
    {
        //Here you can add validations for your form before trying to insert data to your Database

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $this->load->model('register_insert');
            $agregar=$this->register_insert->add_user();
        }
        $this->load->view('register');
    }

  }
?>
```

And finally your model code:

```html
<?php if( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class register_insert extends CI_Model {

   public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
   }

 public function add_user (){

            $data = array(
            'u_nm' =>$this->input->post('u_nm'),
            'pwd' => $this->input->post('pwd'),
            'eid' => $this->input->post('eid'),
            'cno' => $this->input->post('cno'),
            'mbo' => $this->input->post('mbo'),
             );

  $this->db->insert('register', $data);
 }

}
```

For this model you will also need to change your autoload.php

you need to autoload the database library:

```html
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```